# mypy and sqlalchemy: error: Name 'sqlalchemy' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, mypy

I have the following function:

```
def _init_db() -> "sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session":
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///my_db.db")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    # Creating Session
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
    session = Session()
    return session
```

Running `mypy` on the code gives me this error

> error: Name 'sqlalchemy' is not defined

I tried with and without the quotes around `sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session`

How can I add type hints for sqlalchemy classes? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use type hints you have import what you are trying to return. In first example I am trying to define a function returning some sqlite3 stuff without importing sqlite3. After I do import this module everything works fine.

```
In [1]: def init_db() -> sqlite3.Connection:
   ...:     return sqlite3.connection
   ...:
   ...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b64a7629272c> in <module>()
----> 1 def init_db() -> sqlite3.Connection:
      2     return sqlite3.connection

NameError: name 'sqlite3' is not defined

In [2]: import sqlite3

In [3]: def init_db() -> sqlite3.Connection:
   ...:     return sqlite3.connection
   ...:
   ...:

In [4]:
```

Comment: I added `import sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session` at the beginning of my script and got `error: No library stub file for module 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session`. So I guess there is no support for this class.

Comment: Add `import sqlalchemy` at the top or annotate only `Session` instead of the full path.

Answer (score 0):

I got it thanks to gonczor's answer.

I needed to add

`from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session`

at the beginning and then do

```
def _init_db() -> "Session":
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///my_db.db")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    # Creating Session
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
    session = Session()
    return session
```